# C Infinite Loop On While Loop

Tags: c, infinite-loop

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    
 void add(int num){
     while(num < 6){
         add(num+1);
     }
    printf("\n%d",num);
 }

void main(){
    int a = 1;
    add(a);
}
```

Can any one explain me why its going Infinite

> 6
> 6 6
> 6....

And not only

> 6

single time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your loop:

```
 while(num < 6){
     add(num+1);
 }
```

You never modify `num`.  So the loop never exits.  You eventually end up via recursion with a call to `add(5)`.  That calls `add(6)` which prints the value 6 and returns.  Then the prior recursive call calls `add(6)` again because of the loop, and so forth.

Given that you have a recursive function, you don't want a loop here.  This should only be an `if` statement:

```
 void add(int num){
     if(num < 6){
         add(num+1);
     }
    printf("\n%d",num);
 }
```

This will print values from 6 counting down to (in this case) 1.

Answer (score 3):

You don't change the num variable within the loop, try the following:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
        
     void add(int num){
         while(num < 6){
             num++;
             add(num);
         }
        printf("\n%d",num);
     }
    
    void main(){
        int a = 1;
        add(a);
    }
```

> And not only
>
> 6 single time.

Well as it is it will never be only one time even with the infinite loop because of the recursive calls.

To get only a single time you either do:

```
 void add(int num){
     while(num < 6){
         num++;
     }
    printf("\n%d",num);
 }
```

or

```
 void add(int num){
     if(num < 6){
        add(num+1);
     }
    if(num == 6)
      printf("\n%d",num);
 }
```

But not both combined.